# Add Radio button value to summation variable (javascript )

Tags: javascript, radio-button

if I have a variable like sum = 20 and I have a numbers of radio buttons with value(number) for each one of them how can I add the value of  checked radio button  only  to sum variable and when check another radio button value will add to sum variable and remove other checked radio value before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add event listeners to the inputs and change the sum accordingly:

```js
let radios = document.getElementsByClassName("numberRadio");
let number = 20;

sum.innerHTML = number;
for(let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++)
     radios[i].addEventListener("click", addNumbers);
     
function addNumbers(event){
     let total = number;
     for(let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++)
          if(radios[i].checked)
               total += parseInt(radios[i].value);
     sum.innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="numberRadio" id="one" name="number" value="1">
<label for="one">1</label><br>
<input type="radio" class="numberRadio" id="two" name="number" value="2">
<label for="two">2</label><br>
<input type="radio" class="numberRadio" id="three" name="number" value="3">
<label for="three">3</label>
<br><br>
<input type="radio" class="numberRadio" id="four" name="number1" value="4">
<label for="four">4</label><br>
<input type="radio" class="numberRadio" id="five" name="number1" value="5">
<label for="five">5</label><br>
<input type="radio" class="numberRadio" id="six" name="number1" value="6">
<label for="six">6</label>

<p id="sum"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, dude, I appreciate it, but this work for just one group of radio buttons I have multi groups and I wanna make a function for all

Comment: @kyrillosezzat I updated the answer. Please mark the answer as the solution to close the question.